# How to set route params for CRUD application using Redux and API server

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, crud

I'm working on a React/Redux application that needs to make a simple GET request to an API server endpoint (/contents/{id}). Right now I have an action set up to fetch this data:

```
export const fetchInfoPage = id => {
return async dispatch => {
    try {
    const res = await fetch(`${server}/contents/${id}`)
    if (res.ok) {
        const json = await res.json()
        await dispatch(fetchPageRequest())
        await setTimeout(() => {
        dispatch(fetchPageSuccess(json.data))
        }, 1000)
    } else {
        const json = await res.json()
        console.log(res, json)
    }
    } catch (error) {
    dispatch(fetchPageFailure(error))
    console.log(error)
    }
  }
}
```

And here's what `fetchPageSuccess` looks like:

```
const fetchPageSuccess = content => {
    const { id, attributes } = content
    return {
        type: FETCH_PAGE_SUCCESS,
        isFetching: false,
        id: id,
        name: attributes.name,
        content: attributes.content,
        created_by: attributes.created_by,
        updated_by: attributes.updated_by,
        created_at: attributes.created_at,
        updated_at: attributes.updated_at
    }
}
```

I am firing off this action inside of `componentDidMount` in my `InfoPage` component by using `fetchInfoPage(match.params.name)`. The `match.params.name` is set up to match the parameters in the React Route (i.e. /:name/information). I want to instead change this to fetch the data by using an ID number from the JSON while still displaying :name as the route parameter.

I feel like I'm close in getting this wired up but there's a gap in my logic somewhere. Is it possible to do what I'm trying to do here? I also have access to a GET endpoint at `/contents/slug/{slug}`.

Comment: If you are doing Asynchronous work in React, you should be using a library such as Thunk https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-thunk or Axios https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-axios to do the asynchronous work. The "Action" will then call the "Reducer" and update the State. The state changing will in turn update your component. You can pass a parameter to the action, the "id" in your case.

Comment: I'm already using Thunk, and I wanted to get familiar with `async/await` rather than relying on Axios. I'm just confused as to how I can connect name and id together while using this API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was fetching by `slug` instead. On the components where I fetched the data, I created the slug name in `componentDidMount` by using `match.params.name` from my route, then fired off `fetchInfoPage(slugName)` to get the data. I also cleaned up the code quite a bit so here's what `fetchInfoPage` looks like now:

```
export const fetchInfoPage = slug => {
  return async dispatch => {
    try {
      dispatch(fetchPageRequest())
      const res = await fetch(`${server}/contents/slug/${slug}`)
      const contentType = res.headers.get('content-type')
      if (contentType && contentType.includes('application/vnd.api+json')) {
        const json = await res.json()
        if (res.ok) {
          dispatch(fetchPageSuccess(json))
        } else {
          printError(res, json)
          dispatch(fetchPageFailure(res.body))
          dispatch(push('/error'))
        }
      } else {
        console.log('Not valid JSON')
        dispatch(fetchPageFailure(res.body))
        dispatch(push('/error'))
      }
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch(fetchPageFailure(error))
      dispatch(push('/error'))
      console.log(`Network error: ${error.message}`)
    }
  }
}
```

And a `componentDidMount` example:

```
componentDidMount() {
    const { match, fetchInfoPage } = this.props
    const slugName = `${NAMESPACE}-${match.params.name}`
    fetchInfoPage(slugName)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's perfectly fine what you are trying to do. 
Just map the id using your name in the fetchInfoPage from your `json` or you can actually send the `id` to your fetchInfoPage function from component. It has nothing to do with your route params. All you are doing is getting the name from your param and getting the corresponding id using your name. I assume you have a name: id map somewhere.

```
export const fetchInfoPage = name => {
return async dispatch => {
    try {
    const id = getIdFromName(name); // Write a helper function
    const res = await fetch(`${server}/contents/${id}`)
    if (res.ok) {
        const json = await res.json()
        await dispatch(fetchPageRequest())
        await setTimeout(() => {
        dispatch(fetchPageSuccess(json.data))
        }, 1000)
    } else {
        const json = await res.json()
        console.log(res, json)
    }
    } catch (error) {
    dispatch(fetchPageFailure(error))
    console.log(error)
    }
  }
}
```

Your route will still be `/:name/information`

Comment: I see what you are trying to do, but I'm still a little confused about how to map the name to id. In the `getIdFromName` helper function, wouldn't I need to do another `fetch` request to get the data? That seems like it would be redundant since I am already fetching the data inside `fetchInfoPage`.